# What use are constructors in abstract classes?

Tags: java, oop, constructor, abstract-class

Since we can't instantiate an abstract class, then what is the necessity of having constructors in abstract class?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260666/abstract-class-constructor-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Abstract classes are designed to be extended, each constructor from the child [must perform a call to a constructor from the base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013509/class-inheritance-problem-in-java-constructors-with-and-without-params/2013537#2013537), thus you need constructors in your abstract class.

The abstract class is a skeleton and thus makes no sense to instantiate it directly since it is still incomplete (children will provide the rest).

Answer (score 2):

An example:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    private String member;

    public BaseClass(String member)
    {
        this.member = member;
    }

    ... abstract methods...
}

public class ImplementingClass extends BaseClass
{
    public ImplementingClass(String member)
    {
        /* Implementing class must call a constructor from the abstract class */
        super(member);
    }

    ... method implementations...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use a abstract class constructor to execute code that is relevant for every subclass. This way preventing duplicate code

Answer (score 1):

Abstract classes can have fields and non-abstract methods(what makes it an abstract class rater than an interface). The fields probably need to be initialized when a class that extends it is instantiated.

Having a constructor in the abstract class allows you to call `super(foo);` to initialize them as opposed to doing it directly